# How can I install programs downloaded form Internet?

Tags: installation

I can't run programmes that I have just downloaded from the net, like Google Chrome, because I open them with Achieve Manager, but it doesn't work. why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Ubuntu Software Center. Install from there. Don't download apps from the internet when it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

A .deb file, when double-clicked should open with Package Manager.

Anyway do this:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

( change the name of .deb file to the real one )